# Is there any possible reason why I should specify type="button" for my button element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have code that my group developed:

```
<button id="createLink" class="blue" type="button" title="Create Text"></button>
```

Can someone give me some advice on this. My groupmates are specifying the wording type="button". If this already is a button then why is it needed?

Comment: Off topic tip: try and use semantic class names. What is you would like to switch to a style sheet where the buttons should be red. Then you would have to code your CSS like `button.blue { background: red; }`. If you really need a `class` on your button (it's different then all other buttons of type button, and you have multiple instances of that button) consider something like `class="secondary"`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By default, a `<button>` element is `type="submit"`, not `type="button"`.

See [the specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#attr-button-type):

| Keyword | State | Brief description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| submit | Submit Button | Submits the form. |
| reset | Reset Button | Resets the form. |
| button | Button | Does nothing. |

> The **missing value default** and invalid value default are **the
> Submit Button state**.
>
> If the type attribute is in the Submit Button state, the element is
> specifically a submit button.

… or the [previous specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.5):

> type = submit|button|reset [CI]
>  This attribute declares the type of
> the button. Possible values: 
> **submit**: Creates a submit button. This is
> the default value. 
> **reset**: Creates a reset button. 
> **button**: Creates a
> push button.

Comment: Thanks very much. By the way. What is a reset button. I never even knew about that?

Comment: A RESET button is used to reset the fields of a form to the values they had before the user changed any. See http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_INPUT_TYPE_RESET.html

Comment: @Neil—handy to reference an [appropriate specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#input-control-types) too.

Comment: @RobG - I gave the 'htmlcodetutorial.com' reference since it explained a bit more about the reset-button (such as: If you do choose to use have a reset button in your form, consider adding a check if the user actually wants to reset. You can do this by adding an onReset event handler to the <FORM ...> tag) than the one you suggest, which in any case is linked to on the page given by 'specification' in Quentin's answer itself.

Answer (score 2):

Default type of button is `submit` so it will submit your form onclick. so if you want to make it button only then type should be `button`

Answer (score -3):

The type attribute specifies the type of button.

Generally we specify any three of these attributes:

Attribute Values

1. button : The button is a clickable button
2. submit : The button is a submit button (submits the form-data)
3. reset : The button is a reset button (clears form-data)

Hope this is helpfull !!